# MarkerClusterer не видит функцию getPosition()

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps, position

Вывожу на карту фотографии в виде маркеров, которые необходимо кластеризировать. Выводит ошибку: `Uncaught TypeError: marker.getPosition is not a function` в файле markerclusterer.js
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выполняю кластеризацию маркеров по инструкции с оффицеального сайта GoogleMaps. Как исправить ошибку?

Подключаю следующие скрипты:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=****"></script>
<script src="https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/markerclusterer.js"></script>
```

Скрипт выгрузки маркеров и кластеризация:

```
var map;
   function initialize() {
    // Prepare markers array

    var markers = [];
    <% photoList.forEach(function(photo) { %>
    markers.push({
        latLan: new google.maps.LatLng("<%= photo.latit %>", "<%= photo.longit %>"),
        img: "<%= photo.preview %>"
    });
    <% }) %>

    //определение карты
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.42216, 44.31308),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    markers.forEach(function (item) {
        new RichMarker({
            position: item.latLan,
            map: map,
            content: '<div class="google-marker"><img src="'+item.img+'"/></div>',
            shadow: 0
        });
    });
    //Кластеризация
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,
        {imagePath: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/markerclusterer/m'});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте тип вашего JS-элемента. Я подозреваю, что это не объект `Marker`. Дело в том, что в начале массив `markers` заполняется объектами (`markers.push({...})`), а затем вы пытаетесь через `foreach` поменять исходный массив (`markers.forEach(function (item) {...})`), но не делаете этого по понятным причинам - там идет просто перебор всех элементов и создание `RichMarker` который никуда не попадает, и в результате вы передаете в  `MarkerClusterer` массив объектов, созданный еще при наполнении этого массива в `markers.push({...})`.

Уберите ваш блок кода из функции `initialize` (хоть `RichMarker` и соджержит метод `getPosition`, но для начала нужно это убрать) который кажется немного неправильным:

```
markers.forEach(function (item) {
    new RichMarker({
        position: item.latLan,
        map: map,
        content: '<div class="google-marker"><img src="'+item.img+'"/></div>',
        shadow: 0
    });
});
```

Замените убранный код на следующий (я настоятельно не рекомендую менять элементы коллекции через [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), с этим отлично справляется метод [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)):

```
markers = markers.map(function (item) {
    return new RichMarker({
        position: item.latLan,
        map: map,
        content: '<div class="google-marker"><img src="'+item.img+'"/></div>',
        shadow: 0
    });
});
```

Чтобы удостовериться в том, что вы передаете нормальный массив при создании `MarkerClusterer` - поставьте точку останова перед его созданием и посмотрите на переменную `markers`.